# How to stop and restart cumsum using a marker in another column

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

I have a pandas dataframe with values that needs to be totalized inside a period for each device, but the periods ends are marked in another column (an easy identifiable event line). The cumsum must go until it finds this end of period marker and then start again from zero(the first value on the next line).

```
  device_name value end
0   A5         1    False
1   A5         7    False
2   A5         2    True
3   A5         1    False
4   A5         1    False
5   A5         1    False
6   A5         1    True
7   A6         2    False
8   A6         4    False
9   A6         2    False
10  A6         2    True
11  A6         2    False
12  A6         2    False
```

the result should be something like

```
  device_name value end     total
0   A5         1    False    1  
1   A5         7    False    8
2   A5         2    True     10
3   A5         1    False    1
4   A5         1    False    2
5   A5         1    False    3
6   A5         1    True     4
7   A6         2    False    2
8   A6         4    False    6
9   A6         2    False    8
10  A6         2    True     10
11  A6         2    False    2
12  A6         2    False    4
```

I tried cumsum but I can't separate the end of a period from the other, I can iterate over rows and if i find a True on df.end.shift(1) i ignore the last value, but there are at least 60000 and probably there are faster methods, Any suggestion?

Comment: Your output is not logical, why row 2 does not get accumulated while row 10 does? I'll consider the row 2 is a mistake and should be 10, if not please update the question.

Comment: Yes, it was a mistake, I corrected it

Comment: Great, thanks, then it should work as you expect, let me know ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you want to `cumsum` per group until you reach a True. Then, **after** this row, restart the count.

You can use an extra group based on the "end" value (also using a `cumsum`):

```
df['total'] = (df.groupby(['device_name',
                           df['end'].shift(1, fill_value=0).cumsum()])
               ['value'].cumsum())
```

output:

```
   device_name  value    end  total
0           A5      1  False      1
1           A5      7  False      8
2           A5      2   True     10
3           A5      1  False      1
4           A5      1  False      2
5           A5      1  False      3
6           A5      1   True      4
7           A6      2  False      2
8           A6      4  False      6
9           A6      2  False      8
10          A6      2   True     10
11          A6      2  False      2
12          A6      2  False      4
```

*NB. note that I get a different value for row #2*

*NB.2. for purists, the extra group could also be computed using a `groupby`. It doesn't really matter in this case. The internal groups will just not start from zero after the first group, but their name will not be used anywhere in the output.*

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly, I still have to dedicate some time to understand why.

Comment: @PedroSilva sure, let me know if anything is unclear ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
cnt = 0
def fetch_flag_col(x):
    global cnt
    resp = cnt
    if(x): cnt+=1
    return resp

df["flag"] = df["end"].apply(fetch_flag_col)
df["total"] = df.groupby(["device_name ","flag"])["Value"].cumsum()
```

I am not sure if there is a direct function or a sophisticated way to do this using native pandas api's, but using the above method you can achieve the desired result in O(n) time complexity.

What we are doing is, creating a intermediate column called flag, which will help `.cumsum()`, method decide between what range of rows, it has to do the cumulative.